# Average of max - SQL

Tags: sql, syntax-error, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to get the average score, of the most up-voted answer, for each StackOverflow question which does not have an accepted answer.

Using the following query:

```
SELECT AVG(MaxScore) 
FROM
    (SELECT MAX(a.Score) as MaxScore
     FROM Posts a
     JOIN Posts q ON q.Id = a.ParentID
     WHERE q.PostTypeId = 1 AND q.AcceptedAnswerId IS NULL
     GROUP BY q.Id);
```

only gives me: "Incorrect syntax near ';'"

Any ideas why?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you have use ' sign at last of this query. You have remove this sign it will work.

Comment: It is the same error ? after you update your question?

Comment: Unfortunately not, that was just a typo made here when formatting the question (removed now). Thanks anyhow!

Comment: I mean, You are still having the same error message: `Incorrect syntax near ';`

Comment: @karinsofiapaulina Its an silly mistake. Take Care.

Comment: There is no apostrophe in the query.

Comment: @karinsofiapaulina Ah, the error message is actually `Incorrect syntax near ';'`, right? If so, if that were more clear from the question, it would have saved time, as it is then obvious that the error message is complaining about the semicolon.

Comment: Well, typos happens to everyone right? :)

Comment: @karinsofiapaulina That one isn't a typo, is it? I see you do have it correct in the question, but it's far too easy to miss the `'` right before a `"` :) Oh, you edited the question to include it. I didn't even notice that, the message looks the same after the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG(MaxScore) 
FROM
    (SELECT MAX(a.Score) as MaxScore
     FROM Posts a
     JOIN Posts q ON q.Id = a.ParentID
     WHERE q.PostTypeId = 1 AND q.AcceptedAnswerId IS NULL
     GROUP BY q.Id) AS sub;
```

A name for a subquery like this may be required, depending on the database system, even if you don't use it.